# Magento login admin page showed error and then blank

Tags: php, magento

I've looked at the other questions which were similar but haven't been able to fix it.
**Problem:**

Magento admin page first showed a fatal error (I didn't write it down :/). Now it is blank.

**Attempts to Fix**:

I've tried to fix it following the other posts, removing # to uncomment one of the files? But I am very confused as to what all this does.

Comment: If by 'blank' you mean a white screen, that sounds like a fatal error that is preventing any rendering happening at all. Check the end of your PHP error logs - and edit into your question what you find. Your error log location depends on whether you are running locally or are on a shared/dedicated host.

Comment: Hi, I am using GoDaddy, I believe it is a SHARED host!                   Please help! I know it is a fatal error! Yes it is a white screen, the login panel isnt showing up!

Comment: Yes, GoDaddy is usually a shared host account. I don't know how to access the PHP error logs, but I am sure you could determine this yourself by running a web search of "GoDaddy PHP error logs".

Comment: `1146 Table 'statis91_mage2.mage_banners' doesn't exist` means that the mysql table `mage_banners` doesn exist. 

Is this a fresh install? the SQL-file that needs to be imported is quite large, perhaps that godaddy doesn't allow those large files to be added. 

If you installed a new addon/plugin on an existing system there went something wrong with the installation of that (maybe you need to manually import tables to the databse through a `.sql` file?)

Comment: Oh, then I think that might be something I did on Godaddy.com Hosting website in an attempt to fix Magento.. But the error before was the FATAL ERROR one

Comment: Any idea what can be causing the white page? I have manually disabled modules (i think), cleared cache, and looked at the error logs. I believe the problem is [08-Jul-2014 20:29:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in /home/statis91/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 104 ........... but i have no idea what it means

Comment: That means that Magento is trying to load the admin, but fails as sokme function isn't present. Most likely mage_banners, since those DB-tables don't exist either. 
You made changes in an attempt to fix it. Can you undo those changes?

Comment: Yeah I reversed what I did, not sure if that is what caused the mage_banners. Don't know if you use GoDaddy, but in my account I went to cPanel-> (Installatron) My Applications -> view/edit details (magento) -> Files/Tables -> Checked the things I unchecked before UNDER -> statis91_mage2 -> "banners" & "banners_store" . . . I'm not sure whether that is the mage_banners?

Comment: not a user of godaddy. What error do you get now? still the same?

Comment: yeah, there hasn't been a new error in the error log since 7/08. I've been on the admin page everyday (today 7/13/2014). The page is still a white screen.

Comment: any idea what the error is? Is it an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check reports at `/var/report/` if you find any files there, read them, may be you get an idea.
Also if your `system >> tools >> compilation` was enabled and you have installed new module,  you have to disable that module and then delete cache folders and reload.

Comment: Hi! I found two errors!

::::::::::::One of the files in /var/report there was an error:::::::::::::
a:5:{i:0;s:101:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'statis91_mage2.mage_banners' doesn't exist";i:1;s:5717:"#0 /home/statis91/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

::::::::::::::The Second Error::::::::::::::::::

a:5:{i:0;s:63:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away";i:1;s:2695:"#0 /home/statis91/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: Ok that means your module for the banners was not properly installed. atleast its tables are missing. you have to create the tables manually by following its setup files or delete the "banners" entry from the core_resource table and reload the admin.

Comment: @statis-online: those errors would be best added to your question, so the question contains the minimum level of information to be answerable. Would you edit them in?

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this are at times related to many things but my first point of call will be to
1.   Clear my cache, delete any present error log and retry

1. It might be due to file permissions. Did you add files (or moved files from one server to another?).

Comment: Hi! yes I cleared the cache manually using FTP, could you tell me where to find the error log? 

I did move files from some folder to another folder based on instructions from an Extension install. 

Please let me know what steps to take!